# Identification of bird observed in Western Australia near the city of Perth in February

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

This bird was observed during a holiday in Western Australia near the city of Perth in February 2019. Maybe somebody can help me figure out the species.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the bird's name is ***Willie Wagtail*** and It's scientific name is ***Rhipidura leucophrys***..

Comment: That looks right! Brilliant! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. You are likely to get a more positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— You may also wish to take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site.

Comment: The white eyebrow  (“leucophrys”) confirms the ID.